Why does a ResolvedSymbol always have the Canvas view size?
So should the Canvas want to know the size (bounding box) of a resolved symbol, e.g., for placement relative to other symbols or paths drawn directly into it, that is not possible by inspecting the GraphicsContext.ResolvedSymbol.size property?
This is surprising.  Not a blocker for what I want to do but would like to understand why this particular behavior if anyone knows and can explain?
Trivial example to reproduce below, on toggling the button outputs
canvas size: (400.0, 350.0); symbol size: (400.0, 350.0)
toggled
canvas size: (500.0, 450.0); symbol size: (500.0, 450.0)
toggled
canvas size: (400.0, 350.0); symbol size: (400.0, 350.0)

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var large = false
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button {
        large.toggle()
        print("toggled")
      } label: {
        Text("Toggle Size")
      }
      Spacer()
      Canvas { context, size in
        let s0 = context.resolveSymbol(id: 0)!
        print("canvas size: \(size); symbol size: \(s0.size)")
        context.draw(s0, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
      } symbols: {
        Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)))
          .stroke(.green, lineWidth: 10)
          .border(.blue)
          .tag(0)
      }
      .frame(width: large ? 500 : 400, height: large ? 450 : 350)
    }.padding()
  }
}


I think that what you are seeing when you resolve the symbol and examine its size is the bounding rectangle of the Path, this being:

A rectangle containing all path segments

(ref. Path documentation).
So when the symbol is created in this way, it seems that the bounding rectangle uses all the space available. You can restrict it to the same size as the ellipse by applying a .frame modifier to the Path:
Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)))
    .stroke(.green, lineWidth: 10)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300) //  HERE
    .border(.blue)
    .tag(0)


Ah, yes, indeed and thanks for pointing this out.

For the record, here is the modified code from the original question that illustrates the answer provided by Benzy Neez.
The first .draw is the original "circle" unmodified, and the second is it scaled to fit the Canvas view.
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var large = false
  let p1 = Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button {
        large.toggle()
        print("toggled")
      } label: {
        Text("Toggle Size")
      }
      Spacer()
      Canvas { context, size in
        let s0 = context.resolveSymbol(id: 0)!
        print("canvas size: \(size); symbol size: \(s0.size)")
        context.draw(s0, in: p1.boundingRect)
        context.draw(s0, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
      } symbols: {
        p1
          .stroke(.green, lineWidth: 10)
          .frame(width: p1.boundingRect.width, height: p1.boundingRect.height)
          .border(.blue)
          .tag(0)
      }
      .frame(width: large ? 500 : 350, height: large ? 400 : 250)
    }.padding()
  }
}

